# How to send SES raw emails with attachment files from S3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

Im trying to send raw emails with images as attachments using java, the attachment files are present in S3, however, when receiving email the attachment images are corrupted.
I tried reading file from my disk and it worked correctly but somehow not working for S3 files. Here's the code I'm using.

```
                    MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
                    att.setFileName(attachment.getFileName());
                    String attContent = s3.getObjectAsString(emailServiceConfiguration.getAttachmentS3Bucket(), attachment.getPath());
                    DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attContent.getBytes(),"application/png");
                    att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    msg.addBodyPart(att);
```

Please help, I'm stuck here for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

[Q: Can Amazon SES send emails with attachments?](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/)

> You can also send email with attachments programmatically. To include an attachment in your email, construct a new multipart email message. In the message, include a MIME part that contains an appropriate Content-Type header, along with the MIME-encoded content. Next, use the Content-Disposition header to specify whether the content is to be displayed inline or treated as an attachment.

Once you've composed your message, you can use the `SendRawEmail API operation`to send

[Sending raw email using the Amazon SES API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html)

This post covers how to forward emails with attachment in S3 [Forward Incoming Email to an External Destination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/forward-incoming-email-to-an-external-destination/)

Relevant post with necessary code [How to convert raw emails (MIME) from AWS SES to Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62363395/2246345)

Comment: i'm able to send email, but the issue is that attachment images are corrupt upon receiving the email

Comment: @24Circles it might be because of the missing `MIME-encodeding`

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this as im new to this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the bytes from string, use byte array

```
MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
att.setFileName(attachment.getFileName());
S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(emailServiceConfiguration.getAttachmentS3Bucket(), attachment.getPath());
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(s3Object.getObjectContent());
DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(byteArray,"application/png");
att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
msg.addBodyPart(att);
```